# Oracle Forms 10g Run time Error in mozilla

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Am trying to run a sample forms , newly installed .
Oracle Forms 10g
connected to
Oracle XE database 11g - hr schema
while running form

I get an error in Mozilla browser - 'A plugin is needed to display the content'

I have already installed Java and Adobe flash player.

how could we fix this issue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't use the 64-bit version from firefox, because then this can't work.
If you are using the 32-bit version then you need to check that java is enabled in your firefox browser, check out the following [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using%20the%20Java%20plugin%20with%20Firefox) for more information on how to enable java.